# Best free Cross-Platform Library for higher level Matrix, Vector and esp. SparseMatrix operations?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, multiplatform

Our Platforms:

- Windows, Linux, Mac OSX.

Free:

- LGPL compatible

Support high-level operations:

- Eigensystems, SVD, QR, LU, inverse, pseudo inverse (aka Moore-Penrose inverse),...

Support many matrix types and also good performing small matrices e.g. 3x3:

- Sparse, Symmetric,... (and also operations on them!, e.g. pseudoInverse() )

And of course it should be

- efficent
- active development in the last months

It would be nice to link again LAPACK, MKL, ATLAS, etc..

The thing what comes really close is [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) which does not support sparse containers. [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is also great but does not provide pseudo inverse or support sparse matrices (just for saving place).

I also looked on:

- newmat11, boost::uBlas, gsl, IT++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eigen is the best one! It's much better than boost::ublas, you can write C = A*B instead of C = prod(A,B) as in ublas and I have tested the speed it's much faster than ublas.

Answer (score 0):

Eigen3 now has a sparse matrix class, along with interfaces to several popular sparse matrix libraries. If you need to calculate the pseudo inverse to solve a least squares system, you can instead use [Cholesky decomposition](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_linear_least_squares#Inverting_the_matrix_of_the_normal_equations) directly on the normal equations.

Answer (score 0):

NewMat11 is a good, easy to use & fairly lightweight matrix library for high level matrix operations (Eigensystems, SVD, QR, LU, inverse). You can easily declare & construct a matrix from an array as:

```
Matrix M(numRows,numCols);
M << array;
```

Access matrix elements as:

```
M.element(i,j);
```

Take transpose:

```
M.t();
```

Take inverse:

```
M.i();
```

Multiply with just *:

```
M*M
```

And can perform other operations like: SVD, QR, LU etc. fairly easily.

Providing the pseudo-inverse (Moore-Penrose inverse) operation explicitly is not mandatory for a library, because you can calculate it easily by using the transpose & inverse operations as below:

if row > col, then the pseudo-inverse (least-squares solution) can be calculated as:
    M_PseudoInv = (M<sup>T</sup>M)<sup>-1</sup>M<sup>T</sup>

if row < col then the pseudo-inverse (least-norm solution) can be calculated as:
    M_PseudoInv = M<sup>T</sup> (MM<sup>T</sup>)<sup>-1</sup>